# Using text values in Combobox

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to also use text values to populate textbox one to four right now only number values will fetch data in the textbox, I know I am overlooking a pretty simple thing but can't seem to find out what?

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Val(Me.ComboBox1.Value) = ws.Cells(i, "A") Then
        MsgBox Me.ComboBox1.Value
        Me.TextBox1 = ws.Cells(i, "B").Value
        Me.TextBox2 = ws.Cells(i, "C").Value
        Me.TextBox3 = ws.Cells(i, "D").Value
        Me.TextBox4 = ws.Cells(i, "E").Value
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be an `Exit For` in your loop once the values are set?

Comment: Make sense :) Was a bit blind. Thanks

Comment: Suggest you add the Value Property to the `Me.Textbox` lines instead of using the Default member `[Value]` implicitly. Just good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself with the possibility to reverse it.
FYI: sheet is renamed to "Control"

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Sheets("Control")
        Me.ComboBox1.List = .Range("a2", .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 4
        Me("textbox" & i).Value = ""
    Next
    If Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub
    With Sheets("control")
        For i = 1 To 4
            Me("textbox" & i).Value = .Cells(Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex + 2, i + 1).Value
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    If Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub
    Sheets("control").Cells(Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex + 2, "b").Resize(, 4).Value = _
    Array(Me.TextBox1.Value, Me.TextBox2.Value, Me.TextBox3.Value, Me.TextBox4.Value)
End Sub
```